# NativeScript + VirtualBox / VMWare Containing Mac OS

Tags: java, android, macos, native, nativescript

How to run the Nativescript project that we developed under Ms. Windows
but we want to test whether it works on Mac OS or not by connecting the Nativescript to VMWare / VirtualBox containing the Mac OS... What are the steps required to do so?

NB: I tried to connect between Eclipse (java android code) to VMWare / VIrtualBox containing Android OS, and it works. So, I wonder if it applied to do so with the MAC OSX.

Answer (score 2):

- Install the Mac OS (in your case with the chosen virtual machine)
- Follow the instruction for setting up NativeScript under Mac from here
  https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x
- run **tns doctor** at the end to verify all is installed OK
- Clone the repository with your source code (or share the folder with the source locally)
- **tns platform add ios**
- **tns run ios --emulator**

I hope that will help you out.